# How can I measure thread stack depth?

Tags: java, multithreading, profiling

I have a 32-bit Java service with scalability problems: with high user count we run out of memory because of excessive thread count. In the long term, I plan to switch to 64-bit and to reduce the threads-per-user ratio. In the short term, I'd like to reduce the stack size (-Xss, -XX:ThreadStackSize) to get some more headroom. But this is risky because if I make it too small, I'm going to get StackOverflowErrors.

**How can I measure the average and maximum stack size for my application to guide my decision for an optimal -Xss value?** I'm interested in two possible approaches:

1. Measuring a running JVM during integration testing. What profiling tools will report max stack depth?
2. Static analysis of the application looking for deep call hierarchies. Reflection in dependency injection makes it unlikely that this would work.

**Update**: I *know* the long-term right way to fix this problem. Please focus on the question I've asked: how do I *measure* stack depth?

**Update 2**: I got a nice answer on a related question specifically about JProfiler: [Can JProfiler measure stack depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330033/can-jprofiler-measure-stack-depth) (I posted the separate question as per JProfiler's community support recommendations)

Comment: You should consider switching to async model. It doesn't make any sense to have more threads than you have CPU cores in the system.

Comment: @VladLazarenko - agreed. As I said, in the long term I plan to reduce the threads-per-user ratio, but I need a quick fix sooner.

Comment: How many threads are you creating and how are you managing them?  And why do you need a thread-per-user, you cannot reuse the threads and offer thread-per-request?

Comment: @JohnVint - yes, I already have a plan to fix this legacy code to use NIO instead of a thread per socket, but that's not feasible on short timescales. This app is not request/response, but has messages arriving at unpredictable intervals over established sockets.

Comment: @JohnVint Irrelevant.  OP stated that he will be reducing the thread count in the long term.

Comment: @Vlad You may be interested in reading [this](http://www.mailinator.com/tymaPaulMultithreaded.pdf) then.

Comment: @Voo - that is an *excellent* article, thanks! It's nice to see ideas backed up by numbers! Which brings me back to my questions... :-)

Comment: @Voo: Oh, blocking and async is all mixed in that article.. Blocking is never faster. Going trough event notification subsystems like epoll or kqueue, however, adds some overhead but it is nothing compared to tons of LWPs messing up everything. However, I am not sure if you can get a lot of juice out of epoll in Java (i.e. make app absolutely lock-free), I have a feeling that it doesn't expose all of the features.

Comment: @Vlad "Blocking is never faster" - well the benchmarks he shows clearly demonstrate the contrary. Yes conventional wisdom always is "NIO is sooo much faster than IO" but that's the only article I've seen so far that actually backs up the claim with numbers. And he did test epoll and not the older select so that seems fair to me (and how would you use an async framework without some notification system?). But you're more than welcome to actually **show** numbers - atm you're doing exactly the same as anyone else: "Oh we all know that NIO is so much faster, no I don't have measured it".

Comment: @Voo: Let'me shade some light. Blocking has two meaning here, it may be blocking as not using async notifications, or blocking as blocking because it stuck inside the kernel. Now, blocking as w/o async notifications is faster in simple cases. But blocking itself could be deadly in large scale low-latency systems.

Comment: @Vlad Since Paul measured only throughput it's certainly a possibility that latency may be much better with NIO - but again, without numbers I'm not going to believe anything, because the whole area is way too complicated for a mere human to consider everything :) Chris: You could obviously hack hotspot a bit to get the necessary information, I fear reflection doesn't give the necessary information so stack walking in Java wouldn't help. Probably simpler to use Peter's proposal: Reduce stack space until you get a Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get an idea of the stack depth with something like an aspect that can be woven to your code (load time weaver to allow advising all loaded code except system class loader).  The aspect would work around all executed code and would be able to note when you are calling a method and when you return.  You can use this to capture most of your stack usage (you'll miss anything loaded from the system class loader, e.g. java.*).  While not perfect, it avoids having to change your code to gather StackTraceElement[] at sample points and also gets you into non-jdk code that you might not have written.

For example (aspectj):

```
public aspect CallStackAdvice {

   pointcut allMethods() : execution(* *(..)) && !within(CallStackLog);

   Object around(): allMethods(){
       String called = thisJoinPoint.getSignature ().toLongString ();
       CallStackLog.calling ( called );
       try {
           return proceed();
       } finally {
           CallStackLog.exiting ( called );
       }
   }

}

public class CallStackLog {

    private CallStackLog () {}

    private static ThreadLocal<ArrayDeque<String>> curStack = 
        new ThreadLocal<ArrayDeque<String>> () {
        @Override
        protected ArrayDeque<String> initialValue () {
            return new ArrayDeque<String> ();
        }
    };

    private static ThreadLocal<Boolean> ascending = 
        new ThreadLocal<Boolean> () {
        @Override
        protected Boolean initialValue () {
            return true;
        }
    };

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayDeque<String>> stacks = 
         new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayDeque<String>> ();

    public static void calling ( String signature ) {
        ascending.set ( true );
        curStack.get ().push ( signature.intern () );
    }

    public static void exiting ( String signature ) {
        ArrayDeque<String> cur = curStack.get ();
        if ( ascending.get () ) {
            ArrayDeque<String> clon = cur.clone ();
            stacks.put ( hash ( clon ), clon );
        }
        cur.pop ();
        ascending.set ( false );
    }

    public static Integer hash ( ArrayDeque<String> a ) {
        //simplistic and wrong but ok for example
        int h = 0;
        for ( String s : a ) {
            h += ( 31 * s.hashCode () );
        }
        return h;
    }

    public static void dumpStacks(){
        //implement something to print or retrieve or use stacks
    }
}
```

And a sample stack might be like:

```
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.getTds()
public boolean net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.next()
public void net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.close()
public java.sql.Connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties)
public void phil.RandomStackGen.MyRunnable.run()
```

Very slow and has its own memory issues but can be workable to get you the stack information you need.

You can then use the max_stack and max_locals for each method in your stack traces to compute a frame size (see [class file format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1546)) for the method.  Based on the [vm spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#28851) I believe this should be (max_stack+max_locals)*4bytes for the max frame size for a method (long/double occupy two entries on the operand stack/local vars and is accounted for in max_stack and max_locals).

You can easily javap the classes of interest and see the frame values if you don't have that much in your call stacks.  And something like [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial.html) provides you with some easy tools to use to do this on a larger scale.

Once you have this computed, you need to estimate additional stack frames for JDK classes that might be called by you at your max stack points and add that to your stack sizes.  It wont be perfect but it ought to get you a decent starting point for -Xss tuning without hacking around the JVM/JDK.

One other note: I don't know what JIT/OSR does to frame sizes or stack requirements so do be aware that you may have different impacts from -Xss tuning on a cold vs. warm JVM.

**EDIT** had a few hours of down time and threw together another approach.  This is a java agent that will instrument methods to keep track of a max stack frame size and stack depth.  This will be able to instrument most of the jdk classes along with your other code and libraries, giving you better results than the aspect weaver.  You need asm v4 for this to work.  It was more for the fun of it so file this under plinking java for fun, not profit.

First, make something to track the stack frame size and depth:

```
package phil.agent;

public class MaxStackLog {

    private static ThreadLocal<Integer> curStackSize = 
        new ThreadLocal<Integer> () {
        @Override
        protected Integer initialValue () {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    private static ThreadLocal<Integer> curStackDepth = 
        new ThreadLocal<Integer> () {
        @Override
        protected Integer initialValue () {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    private static ThreadLocal<Boolean> ascending = 
        new ThreadLocal<Boolean> () {
        @Override
        protected Boolean initialValue () {
            return true;
        }
    };

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Integer> maxSizes = 
        new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Integer> ();
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Integer> maxDepth = 
        new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Integer> ();

    private MaxStackLog () { }

    public static void enter ( int frameSize ) {
        ascending.set ( true );
        curStackSize.set ( curStackSize.get () + frameSize );
        curStackDepth.set ( curStackDepth.get () + 1 );
    }

    public static void exit ( int frameSize ) {
        int cur = curStackSize.get ();
        int curDepth = curStackDepth.get ();
        if ( ascending.get () ) {
            long id = Thread.currentThread ().getId ();
            Integer max = maxSizes.get ( id );
            if ( max == null || cur > max ) {
                maxSizes.put ( id, cur );
            }
            max = maxDepth.get ( id );
            if ( max == null || curDepth > max ) {
                maxDepth.put ( id, curDepth );
            }
        }
        ascending.set ( false );
        curStackSize.set ( cur - frameSize );
        curStackDepth.set ( curDepth - 1 );
    }

    public static void dumpMax () {
        int max = 0;
        for ( int i : maxSizes.values () ) {
            max = Math.max ( i, max );
        }
        System.out.println ( "Max stack frame size accummulated: " + max );
        max = 0;
        for ( int i : maxDepth.values () ) {
            max = Math.max ( i, max );
        }
        System.out.println ( "Max stack depth: " + max );
    }
}
```

Next, make the java agent:

```
package phil.agent;

public class Agent {

    public static void premain ( String agentArguments, Instrumentation ins ) {
        try {
            ins.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch ( 
                new JarFile ( 
                    new File ( "path/to/Agent.jar" ) ) );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        ins.addTransformer ( new Transformer (), true );
        Class<?>[] classes = ins.getAllLoadedClasses ();
        int len = classes.length;
        for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            Class<?> clazz = classes[i];
            String name = clazz != null ? clazz.getCanonicalName () : null;
            try {
                if ( name != null && !clazz.isArray () && !clazz.isPrimitive ()
                        && !clazz.isInterface () 
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Long" )
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Boolean" )
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Integer" )
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Double" ) 
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Float" )
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Number" ) 
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Class" )
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Byte" ) 
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Void" )
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Short" ) 
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.System" )
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Runtime" )
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.Compiler" )
                        && !name.equals ( "java.lang.StackTraceElement" )
                        && !name.startsWith ( "java.lang.ThreadLocal" )
                        && !name.startsWith ( "sun." ) 
                        && !name.startsWith ( "java.security." )
                        && !name.startsWith ( "java.lang.ref." )
                        && !name.startsWith ( "java.lang.ClassLoader" )
                        && !name.startsWith ( "java.util.concurrent.atomic" )
                        && !name.startsWith ( "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap" )
                        && !name.startsWith ( "java.util.concurrent.locks." )
                        && !name.startsWith ( "phil.agent." ) ) {
                    ins.retransformClasses ( clazz );
                }
            } catch ( Throwable e ) {
                System.err.println ( "Cant modify: " + name );
            }
        }

        Runtime.getRuntime ().addShutdownHook ( new Thread () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                MaxStackLog.dumpMax ();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

The agent class has the [premain](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) hook for instrumentation.  In that hook, it adds a class transformer that instruments in the stack frame size tracking.  It also adds the agent to the boot class loader so that it can process jdk classes, too.  To do that, we need to retransform anything that might be loaded already, like String.class.  But, we have to exclude a variety of things that are used by the agent or the stack logging which lead to infinite loops or other problems (some of that was found by trial and error).  Finally, the agent adds a shutdown hook to dump the results to stdout.

```
public class Transformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    @Override
    public byte[] transform ( ClassLoader loader, 
        String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer )
            throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        if ( className.startsWith ( "phil/agent" ) ) {
            return classfileBuffer;
        }

        byte[] result = classfileBuffer;
        ClassReader reader = new ClassReader ( classfileBuffer );
        MaxStackClassVisitor maxCv = new MaxStackClassVisitor ( null );
        reader.accept ( maxCv, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG );

        ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter ( ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES );
        ClassVisitor visitor = 
            new CallStackClassVisitor ( writer, maxCv.frameMap, className );
        reader.accept ( visitor, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG );
        result = writer.toByteArray ();
        return result;
    }
}
```

The transformer drives two separate transformations - one to figure out the max stack frame size for each method and one to instrument the method for recording.  It might be doable in a single pass but I didn't want to use the ASM tree API or spend more time figuring it out.

```
public class MaxStackClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {

    Map<String, Integer> frameMap = new HashMap<String, Integer> ();

    public MaxStackClassVisitor ( ClassVisitor v ) {
        super ( Opcodes.ASM4, v );
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod ( int access, String name, 
        String desc, String signature,
            String[] exceptions ) {
        return new MaxStackMethodVisitor ( 
            super.visitMethod ( access, name, desc, signature, exceptions ), 
            this, ( access + name + desc + signature ) );
    }
}

public class MaxStackMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {

    final MaxStackClassVisitor cv;
    final String name;

    public MaxStackMethodVisitor ( MethodVisitor mv, 
        MaxStackClassVisitor cv, String name ) {
        super ( Opcodes.ASM4, mv );
        this.cv = cv;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMaxs ( int maxStack, int maxLocals ) {
        cv.frameMap.put ( name, ( maxStack + maxLocals ) * 4 );
        super.visitMaxs ( maxStack, maxLocals );
    }
}
```

The MaxStack*Visitor classes handle figuring out the max stack frame size.

```
public class CallStackClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {

    final Map<String, Integer> frameSizes;
    final String className;

    public CallStackClassVisitor ( ClassVisitor v, 
        Map<String, Integer> frameSizes, String className ) {
        super ( Opcodes.ASM4, v );
        this.frameSizes = frameSizes;
        this.className = className;
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod ( int access, String name, 
        String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions ) {
        MethodVisitor m = super.visitMethod ( access, name, desc, 
                             signature, exceptions );
        return new CallStackMethodVisitor ( m, 
                 frameSizes.get ( access + name + desc + signature ) );
    }
}

public class CallStackMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {

    final int size;

    public CallStackMethodVisitor ( MethodVisitor mv, int size ) {
        super ( Opcodes.ASM4, mv );
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitCode () {
        visitIntInsn ( Opcodes.SIPUSH, size );
        visitMethodInsn ( Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "phil/agent/MaxStackLog",
                "enter", "(I)V" );
        super.visitCode ();
    }

    @Override
    public void visitInsn ( int inst ) {
        switch ( inst ) {
            case Opcodes.ARETURN:
            case Opcodes.DRETURN:
            case Opcodes.FRETURN:
            case Opcodes.IRETURN:
            case Opcodes.LRETURN:
            case Opcodes.RETURN:
            case Opcodes.ATHROW:
                visitIntInsn ( Opcodes.SIPUSH, size );
                visitMethodInsn ( Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC,
                        "phil/agent/MaxStackLog", "exit", "(I)V" );
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        super.visitInsn ( inst );
    }
}
```

The CallStack*Visitor classes handle instrumenting methods with code to call the stack frame logging.

And then you need a MANIFEST.MF for the Agent.jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: phil.agent.Agent
Boot-Class-Path: asm-all-4.0.jar
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
```

Finally, add the following to your java command line for the program you want to instrument:

```
-javaagent:path/to/Agent.jar
```

You will also need to have the asm-all-4.0.jar in the same directory as the Agent.jar (or change Boot-Class-Path in the manifest to reference the location).

A sample output might be:

```
Max stack frame size accummulated: 44140
Max stack depth: 1004
```

This is all a bit crude but works for me to get going.

Note: the stack frame size isn't a total stack size (still don't really know how to get that one).  In practice, there are a variety of overheads for the thread stack.  I found that I usually needed between 2 and 3 times the reported stack max frame size as a -Xss value.  Oh, and be sure to do the -Xss tuning without the agent loaded as it adds to your stack size requirements.

Comment: The only weakness which I can see in your approach is that it won't handle when an exception is thrown from a method further down the stack. This would require a try/finally block.

Answer (score 5):

I would reduce the `-Xss` setting in a test environment until you see a problem. Then add some head room.

Reducing your heap size would give your application more space for thread stacks.

Just switching to a 64-bit OS could give your application more memory as most 32-bit OSes only allow about 1.5 GB for each application, however a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS can use up to 3-3.5 GB depending on the OS.

Comment: Yes, we're already trying this approach, but right now the test is just binary: do we get StackOverflowError or not? I'd like a more detailed understanding of the actual stack usage of the application. Good point about heap size, I'd forgotten that. Yes, 64-bit is in the plans for long term but the app has remaining 32-bit native dependencies that need work.

Comment: +1 Although this is a trial-and-error approach, it will get the job done.  It's too bad `jvisualvm` doesn't offer information like this.

Comment: Even though you have 32-bit native code, a 64-bit OS would give you more memory even with a 32-bit JVM.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - oops, I misread your "64-bit OS" point. Yes, we're already running on 64-bit OS and are taking advantage of the additional RAM.

Comment: Can you move your 32-bit native library to a stand alone JVM which is available as a service to your front end. i.e. The clients connect to a 64-bit JVM server with no 32-bit libraries which in turn connects to a JVM which holds your native libraries.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - not in the short term. Converting to 64-bit libraries is on the ~4 month timescale, so not worth that radical change. But this is way off track. What I really want to know is how can I measure stack usage?

Comment: 4 months sounds a long way off to me. I suggest you test you system to see how much stack it needs, but it may be that reducing it won't fix you problems for very long.

Answer (score 3):

There is no readily usable tooling in the Java VM to query the stack depth in bytes. But you can get there. Here are some pointers:

- Exceptions contain arrays of stack frames which gives you the methods which were called.
- For each method, you can find [the `Code` attribute](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1546) in the `.class` file. This attribute contains the frame size per method in the field `max_stack`.

So what you need is a tool that compiles a `HashMap` which contains method name + file name + line number as keys and the value `max_stack` as values. Create an `Throwable`, fetch the stack frames from it with `getStackTrace()` and then iterate over the `StackTraceElement`s.

Note:

> Each entry on the operand stack can hold a value of any Java virtual machine type, including a value of type long or type double.

So each stack entry is probably 64bits, so you need to multiply `max_stack` with 8 to get bytes.