# Can JProfiler measure stack depth?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, jprofiler

This is closely related to another question: [How can I measure thread stack depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328679/how-can-i-measure-thread-stack-depth)

Can JProfiler watch threads and measure where the deepest stacks occur? If so, how can I do that? I'd like find spots in my application where I'm getting dangerously close to triggering a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JProfiler does not have this as a feature directly. However, you can do the following:

- Record CPU data with sampling and no filters
- go to the call tree view in the CPU section
- export the call tree in XML format, selecting the "entire tree" option at the bottom of the file chooser dialog
- write a small program that analyzes the exported XML file and finds the most deeply nested elements

You can also automate this with offline profiling and a trigger to record CPU data and save a snapshot. With the "jpexport" command line executable, you can then export the call tree from the saved snapshot.